# How to select multiple images from gallery for android and iOS device using xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms. I am creating an app that can run on Android and iOS both. I have to select multiple images from gallery for both devices.

But, I am unable to select multiple images at a time. I can select single image with help of media picker (`CrossMedia`).

Please update me how I can select multiple images from gallery for both devices using xamarin.forms?

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Comment: You will need to modify CrossMedia (its source is on GitHub) or write your own.  I don't think there is any existing code that will do this out-of-the-box for you.

Comment: It means there is no particular control in xamarin.forms that can select multiple images from gallery?

Comment: not that I'm aware of

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you update me the url of github where I can get the code of CrossMedia?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for giving the url for the code. I got the code and I am trying to make changes in code so that it can select multiple images, But unfortunately I am not getting any success in it. Do you have any idea where should I make changes in code, so that it can select multiple images. I got a picker(MediaPickerController) and I think I should make change in its propertiesnb but unfortunately there is no property that I can select for multiple image selection. Please update if you have any idea about this.

Comment: apparently on iOS, the default Image picker only allows single selection.  For multiples you would need to write a custom control, or find some third party implementation and use that instead.

Comment: Do you know any third party control or any code that may be helpful in multiple image selection. Please provide if you have any idea about this.

Comment: HI Jason, Do you have any idea for multiple image selection for android device. I am not able to select multiple image from gallery in android device through xamarin.forms. Please update if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly for select multiple images in Xamarin Forms, you should do a dependency service for each platform.

In Android use:

```
.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
```

Ex:

```
  [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (MediaService))]
  namespace MyProject
  {
  public class MediaService : Java.Lang.Object, IMediaService
  {
    public MediaService ()
    {
    }

    public void OpenGallery()
    {

        Toast.MakeText (Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "Select max 20 images", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        var imageIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ActionPick);
        imageIntent.SetType ("image/*");
        imageIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
        imageIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(
            Intent.CreateChooser (imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);



       }

     }
   }
```

In IOS:

```
Install this control: ELCImagePicker
```

And:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (MediaService))]
namespace MyProject
{
public class MediaService: IMediaService, IMessanger
{

    public MediaService ()
    {
    }
    public void OpenGallery()
    {

        var picker = ELCImagePickerViewController.Instance;
        picker.MaximumImagesCount = 15;

        picker.Completion.ContinueWith (t => {
            picker.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>
                {
                    //dismiss the picker
                    picker.DismissViewController(true,null);

                    if (t.IsCanceled || t.Exception != null) {
                    } else {
                        Util.File.Path = new List<string>();

                        var items = t.Result as List<AssetResult>;
                        foreach (var item in items) {
                            Util.File.Path.Add (item.Path);
                        }

                        MessagingCenter.Send<IMessanger> (this, "PostProject");
                    }
                });
        });
        var topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        while (topController.PresentedViewController != null) {
            topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
        }
        topController.PresentViewController (picker, true, null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the photos in Android example?

Comment: ExtraAllowMultiple supports API 18 and above only

Comment: ELCImagepicker can not be found in NuGet store anymore, what are the other options ?