# Selecting Multiple Image From Default Gallery Cross Platform Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

```
photoPick.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("bla", "blablabla ", "blablablabla");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

    if (file == null)
        return;

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {

        var stream = file.GetStream();
        file.Dispose();
        return stream;
    });
};
```

for ex. `List<image> = ImageSource.FromStream ....`

Can we add photos to list with after multiple selection ?  And how can i make multiple selection each platforms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select multiple images from gallery for android and iOS device using xamarin.forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750101/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-for-android-and-ios-device-using-xama)

Comment: No that isn't solution for this problem, i want to write each platform but there is(in link , i saw last week) platform only solution.

Comment: No source on web, i m searching "how can i make multiple selection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer) for each platform.
In those custom renderer, you should take multiple image url etc in the native platform 
and than passed the data to xamarin form side via custom renderer

Comment: It will be fix. Thanks from future :)