# To pick multiple images from gallery

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to pick multiple images from gallery in xamarin.forms? I have tried MediaPl ugin picker but it doesn't allows to pickup multiple photos

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750101/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-for-android-and-ios-device-using-xama/34141450#34141450

Comment: @LukasLustenberger thank you i will try that

Answer (score -2):

A Nuget package called GMImagePicker is available on nuget.org 
Full Source can be download from here
 https://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/gmimagepicker-ported-to-xamarin-ios/

Comment: It will allow you to select multiple images from gallery