# Xamarin Forms: How to select multiple images from gallery for android and IOS device and how to show it in the UI

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, photo

Same thread found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750101/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-for-android-and-ios-device-using-xama/34141450#34141450). But the answer is not complete.

Android part multiple image selection is working with that code, but didn't tell how to show the selected images in UI?

For IOS suggesting to install `ELCImagePicker`, but that Nuget is not available in Nuget store.

So anybody please suggest a solution for this feature?

Comment: the best library for Xamrin.forms
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: @B.mansouri It only allows to select a single photo, I am looking for multiple photo selection and show the selected pictures it in UI.

Comment: check this link https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/