# Xamarin form : How to select multiple files form filepicker

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have developed to pick file form mobile, but need to pickup multpple file here is my code

```
try
        {
            FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            if (fileData == null)
                return; // user canceled file picking

            string fileName = fileData.FileName;
            string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

            System.Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

need to know how i can select multiple files

Comment: Which type of file you want to pick,such as image,doc,or video?

Comment: i need for both can be image or document, no video

Comment: There is no direct way to select multiple files.Suggest that trying native ways to do.If select images you can try these ways.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750101/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-for-android-and-ios-device-using-xama and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127427/select-multiple-image-from-gallery-in-ios.Docs can refer to this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513556/select-multiple-files-with-intent-action-get-content However ios have less samples to select multi files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xamarin Essentials FilePicker to select multiple files.It is stable now and support Android,iOS and UWP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android